# Categorical dependent and independent variable

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, biostatistics

I am interested in investigating the impact of the localization of malignant lung tumors on the pattern of lymph node metastases. The localization of the lung tumor is a categorical independent variable divided in upper lobe, middle lobe and lower lobe. The only way I can think of to investigate this research question is to consider the dependent variable (divided in eg intrapulmonary lymph nodes, mediastinal lymph nodes, extrathoracic lymph nodes,...) also categorical and thus use a chi squared test for statistical analysis.

My question is if there is a better way to investigate the impact of the localization of malignant tumors on the pattern of lymph node metastases.

Comment: Why did you tag the question as multilevel? What about the data is multilevel? Is it that there are three observations per individual? Can you say more about your data?

Comment: I accidentally tagged it as multilevel. I am dividing the localization of the tumor in 8 subgroups. The level of lymph node metastases is divided in 10 subgroups. It is possible that 1 tumor is metastasized to multiple levels of lymph nodes. My sample size consists of 210 patients. I want to predict the pattern of lymph node metastases. For example: primary lung tumors of the upper lobe typically metastasize to extrathoracic lymph nodes and to intrapulmonary lymph nodes but not to mediastinal lymph nodes. This might differ for primary tumors in the middle lobe.

Comment: Your comment seems to contradict your question: In the question you speak of three levels of the dependent variable, in your comment of eight. Concerning the ten levels of lymph node metastases: Are these actually categories or is this a binned numeric variable? Can you please clarify what your goal is? Are you predicting one categorial variable on basis of one other variable? And what do you intend to use the chi square test for?